# Setting antd DatePicker value from the DB via an async fetch

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, datepicker, antd

i'm using Ant Design React library to populate a Table, each row containing some editable text, editable date and buttons.
it is supposed to look like the image below:

[stored requests screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZz30.png)

the contents of the Table are populated from the DB, using the Django REST API.
The problem appears with getting the date value from the database and passing it to the DatePicker.value.

i'm only aware of async way of fetching data with React from the REST API, in the following way:

```
async function getDate(props, key)
{
   var valDate = dayjs();

   let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/authapi/notes/'+key+'/', {
      method:'GET',
      headers:{
         'Content-type':'application/json',
         'Authorization':'Bearer ' + String(props.autht.access)
      }
   });

   console.log("Async fetch response: ", response);
   let data = await response.json();

   if (response.status === 200)
   {
      valDate = dayjs(data.pub_date);
      console.log("Date: ", valDate);
   }
   else if (response.statusText === 'Unauthorized')
   {
      logoutUser();
   }
   return valDate;
}
```

when i populate the columns of the Table, if DatePicker is used to display the data from the DB and not from  a const, it says "Invalid Date", most likely because of the getDate being async:

```
export function StoredRequests(props)
{
   const [reqdata, setData]  = useState([]);
   useEffect(() => {getRequests()}, []);   /* getRequests is also an async function that receives full data for the Table, like getDate does for a specific key. getRequests calls setData to make the Table updatable via useState/useEffect magic. */

   //DEBUG, let's call getDate() just to see what it returns
   var constDate = getDate(props,96);
   console.log(constDate);   //a Promise?

   //some of the columns omitted here for brevity
   const columns = [
      {
         title: 'Search Request',
         dataIndex: 'request',
         width: '25%',
         editable: true,
      },
      {
         title: 'From Date',
         dataIndex: 'pub_date',
         width: '25%',
         render: (_, record) =>
            reqdata.length >=1 ? (
               <DatePicker
                  className = {record.key}
                  presets = {rangePresets}
                  showTime
                  format = "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss"
                  onChange = {onChange}
                  onOk = {onOk}
                  value = {dayjs(getDate(props, record.key), "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss")}
               />
            ) : null,
      },
   ];

   const columnsProcessed = columns.map((col) => {
      if (!col.editable)
      {
         return col;
      }
      return {
         ...col,
         onCell: (record) => ({
            record,
            editable: col.editable,
            dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
            title: col.title,
            handleSave,
         }),
      };
   });

   return (
      <Table
         components={components}
         rowClassName={()=>'editable-row'}
         bordered
         columns={columnsProcessed}
         dataSource={reqdata}
      />
   );
}
```

Result:
[Invalid Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Da6.png)

i'm assuming the value attribute of the DatePicker cannot be set via an async function.
If the value is set not to value = {dayjs(getDate(props, record.key), "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss")}, but to the current date, e.g. value = {dayjs(), "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss")} - the data is displayed correctly.
What would be the correct way to work around this?
Instead of fetch i could use axios, but it's also async.

If instead of the DatePicker, the data is printed in an editable cell of the Table (like the ones to the left of the Date, e.g. 'Search Request' in the screens), it is being displayed in the Table without issues, but DatePicker seems so much more usable from the UX standpoint.
Thank you!

Comment: Datepicker value needs dayjs object. Don't pass any value other than dayjs. `getData` already returns a dayjs object. Try `value={getDate(props, record.key)}` without date format. You should avoid getting date from backend or try some other method. Datepicker may not work. I recommand to get all dates along with your data if you can

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique thank you, but when i set `value={getDate(props, record.key)}` the Table just does not draw, with "Uncaught TypeError: date.clone is not a function".
i believe the problem is that getDate is async.
Wondering if there's a sync way to get data via REST API...

"You should avoid getting date from backend or try some other method."
The user story is to manage a library of search requests, each request can have some terms to look for, and a date to limit the scope. Essentially avoiding getting dates from backend means DatePicker is not suitable for this scenario.

Comment: You can create a custom date picker component. Pass all required props to that component. Create a state to show loading instead of datepicker. Once you get the date from API, show the datepicker and pass that value. `Uncaught TypeError: date.clone is not a function` When you try to pass invalid value to datepicker, it will throw this error. Console the value and try to fix that

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique, thank you.
Will look at the custom component, yes - seems like Antd does not fit out of the box.

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique, as for "Console the value and try to fix that" - that was done in my code with `constDate`.
getDate returns immediately, it says "constDate:  
Object { "$L": "en", **"$d": Invalid Date,** "$x": {}, "$y": NaN, "$M": NaN, "$D": NaN, "$W": NaN, "$H": NaN, "$m": NaN, "$s": NaN, … }"
After that, in the console, we get the date printed as part of getDate's execution, it being async. That's on the picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Da6.png).

Comment: Can you create a code sandbox?

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique, thank you very much! Seem to have figured it out.
(not sure if code sandbox can be implemented with a backend.. will try next time).
Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i made it overcomplicated, and the trick is to pass the date as part of the `record` set:

```js
const columns = [
      {
         title: 'Search Request',
         dataIndex: 'request',
         width: '25%',
         editable: true,
      },
      {
         title: 'From Date',
         dataIndex: 'pub_date',
         width: '25%',
         render: (_, record) =>
            reqdata.length >=1 ? (
               <DatePicker
                  className = {record.key}
                  presets = {rangePresets}
                  showTime
                  format = "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss"
                  onChange = {onChange}
                  onOk = {onOk}
                  value = {dayjs(record.pub_date)} //here, instead of doing an async call
               />
            ) : null,
      },
   ];
```